# Python 2.5.2 continued

Tags: python, ironpython

This is a continuation of my question Python2.5.2
The code i developed is working fine with clr.Addreference().
Now thee problem is I have to load ny script which uses dll developed in .NET to another application.They had used QT for its implementation.There is a Script console in that application.When ii entered 'import clr' ,it was saying 'No module named clr' or 'Cannot import clr'.What shall i do?

Comment: What does "load to another application" mean?  Why didn't you copy the .NET DLL?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't be able to run your script in that application. The script console in that QT application doubtlessly uses plain ol' CPython instead of IronPython. There's no real good way to change that without significant surgery to the application that's hosting the python console.

Comment: Thank you .now i got it.But i cant change it.I m a user of that application.Can u suggest anything that i can do ?